# Can't confirm wine installation on ubuntu12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, wine

It might be a stupid question, but, is there any way to install Wine on Ubuntu 12.04 without having to accept the EULA?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in an virtual machine in VMwar Workstation 9.

I wanted to install Wine via the following three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-reopsitory ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.4-i386
```

By the way, is it correct to choose `wine1.4-i386`? It was suggested when I simply typed `wine`. The message was:

```
the program 'wine' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install wine1.4-i386"
```

It all worked well, until I had to click to accept the EULA. For any reason, the clicks on `<ok>` weren't accepted, and I can't get further.

So it seems, that a solution would be, if it is possible to install Wine without having to **click** on `<ok>`. Is this possible?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the TAB key to get focus on the OK and then you can hit enter.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please help me further? Wine is now installed, and I have a program (OpenMaX from ethz). This program doesn't need to be installed, but it has two dll-files which it needs, and which should be (in windows) located in the same directory as the .exe. I have put the three files (2dll + 1exe) in the Program File directory of wine, but it doesn't work. Could you please help me?